# How to package a txt file with my xna game for distribution

Tags: c#, xna

So I have a XNA that that uses data stored on a txt. When I want to access it I tell the program exactly where the file is stored, in this case it is "C:\Users\OliverBarnum\Desktop\" + 'Leaderboard.txt'"

I am using visual studio to package my game for publication. Of course the new user will not be named Oliver Barnum and he will probably not know the put the txt on their desktop.

How can I tell my program where the txt is installed on the computer or how could I associate the txt with the xna package?

Comment: Well, I don't know a lot about XNA, but if it is .NET, you may add the file as an embedded resource, don't you?

Comment: Have your program create the file in the location you expect it to be in.  I don't suggest creating the file on the Desktop.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this question isn't really XNA-specific. The only extra option XNA gives you is the content pipeline - which is only suitable for read-only content. Other than that, all of the usual .NET methods are available to you. But before we can tell you which method to use (and how) you need to tell us what exactly the file is used for (when is it read/written? by what users?) and how is your app distributed (is this a ClickOnce question?)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
private const string DIR = @"Content/Levels/";


private void WriteFile()
{        
     string filename = "dummy.txt";
     string targetDirectory = DIR + filename;

     if (!Directory.Exists(LEVELS_DIR))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(LEVELS_DIR);

     StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
     data.Append("foo");

     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
     {
         writer.WriteLine(data);
     }
}
```